# How to avoid greatest function here?

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I have a SQL query like this..

```
 SELECT v1.a,v2.b,v3.c FROM view1 v1 JOIN view2 v2 JOIN view3 v3 WHERE
    GREATEST(v1.date,v2.date,v3.date) >= to_date('2013-10-15','yyyy-mm-dd');
```

Greatest function is very expensive and causing a performance issue...can you suggest another way of implementing this WHERE logic.

Comment: replace `to_date('2013-10-15','yyyy-mm-dd')` with just `'2014-10-15'` might solve ur problem

Comment: don't you have any columns to join on? As it stands, it's a bit of a weird query.

Comment: I gave a sample use case for using the greatest function....... and yes need to specify join condition.

Comment: @mvp I was looking for the same..

Comment: Your query does not work, since you do not specify any join condition. Provide your full query then you will get some help

Comment: The GREATEST() function isn't particularly expensive. What's expensive is the way you're using it in the WHERE clause to force testing against every row of each table rather than any chance of using indexes. The query really needs to be restructured.

Comment: provide join conditions and a description of what you are actually trying to achieve (because your query doesn't seem likely to be useful)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that solves the performance issue, but OR would also work:

```
WHERE v1.date >= ? or v2.date >= ? or v3.date >= ?
```

Comment: I also need this greatest date in the select list of columns.

Comment: I don't think `OR` is going to improve it a lot, if at all

Comment: You can use GREATEST in the select list. It should not have any negative performance impact there.

Comment: @mvp: Me neither. `OR` is notoriously tricky to optimize. Just wanted to throw out the option.

Comment: True, impact will not be negative. But positive is also not likely